# How to skip the Paging attributes in Get Request in Springboot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am new to REST APIs and I am developing a Get request. Previously I was sending all the objects in simple get request. Now I have implemented Pagination as well, for time being the goal is to let the from-end apis work and they will implement pagination gradually else they have to do lot of changes.

The previous api is `{{base_url}}/api/leads/new`

With Pagination`{{base_url}}/api/leads/new?pageNumber=1&pageSize=10`

Below is the code snippet.

**The goal is to allow user to skip pageNumber and pageSize attributes along with their keys.**

So that their previous api continues to work.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = { "pageNumber", "pageSize" } )
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getNewLeadsDetails(@RequestParam(value = "pageNumber" , required = false, defaultValue = "0") int pageNumber ,@RequestParam(value = "pageSize", required = false,  defaultValue = "10") int pageSize,Authentication authentication,
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) { 
    return leadService.getNewLeads(pageNumber,pageSize,authentication);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JBNizet the question is, is there a way we can skip the paging attributes in our request all together and in that case the result will consist of complete list of data.

Comment: You could use `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` to implement pagination (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting)

Comment: @mtshaikh I have already done that. The question is regarding controller i.e. api.

Comment: Sure. Create a separate method without a `params` attribute in the RequestMapping annotation: it will be called if the user doesn't provide these parameters.

Comment: @JBNizet I was also thinking the same. After doing some research for last 2 days I found no other way.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. If you came up with that idea yourself why are you still asking? Why do you not like that approach? You could also just remove `defaultValue = "0"`, make your parameter an `Integer` and the use `if(null == pageNumber) callWithoutPageable(...) else callWithPageable(...);`

Comment: @cmoetzing I need both urls to work. What you said won't work when user would not provide "pageNumber"(key) in the url. I was bit over ambitious.

Comment: The code I posted below does exactly what you asked for in your first comment:
If the attributes are provided use paging, if they are not, do not use paging and return all results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use default pagination like below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getNewLeadsDetails(Pageable pageable, Authentication authentication,
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) { 
  if(null == pageable) {
      return leadService.getNewLeads(authentication);
  } else {
      return leadService.getNewLeads(pageable.getPageNumber(),pageable.getSize(),authentication);
  }
}
```

Just change request url and replace from pageNumber to page and pageSize to size.

Comment: and how would we hit it. Like if I had to pass data what would be my request url? How would page and pageSize would be sent from front-end

Comment: with Pagination sample URL: http://{base-url}/new?page=0&size=10   
without Pagination sample URL: http://{base-url}/new

Comment: correct answer but in case someone missed to add right framework
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = { "pageNumber", "pageSize" } )
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getNewLeadsDetails(@RequestParam(value = "pageNumber" , required = false) Integer pageNumber ,@RequestParam(value = "pageSize", required = false) Integer pageSize, Authentication authentication,
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) { 
    if(null == pageSize || null == pageNumber) {
        return leadService.getNewLeads(authentication);
    } else {
        return leadService.getNewLeads(pageNumber,pageSize,authentication);
    }
}
```

Your service does allow both, if not set do not use paging.